# Restore MySQL database as update for old rows, don't delete new rows

Tags: mysql

So at the company I work for, someone didn't include a `WHERE` clause for their `UPDATE`. I walked in to find a ton of data overwritten. Luckily, I keep backups twice daily. Unfortunately, there are several different applications that update and add to the database several times per day.

**My question is this:** Is there a way to restore the affected rows back to their uncorrupted state, and keep the new rows as they are now?

Yes, I'm relatively new to the MySQL environment, so I'm not entirely sure what to look for in this case. Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: Do you have _binary logs_ enabled? They are sometimes also called _roll-forward-logs_.

Comment: Unfortunately, there was no logging enabled on the server, I found that out after I got into it. The previous I.T. had not set that part up.

Comment: Bad luck. Then I'd try to restore to a new DB and somehow migrate the lost data from $newDB to $realDB. But that depends on the oparations the other apps have already done, i.e. whether the operations would get invalidated/pointless if the lost data would re-appear.

Comment: I was hoping to avoid the manual aspect. I figured I could do a series of `UPDATE` statements with appropriate where clauses, but that would take while as there are around 9000 rows or so that were affected. There's no way to merge and keep the remote data for the affected rows on conflict?

Comment: I'm really not sure. _Perhaps_ [INSERT ... ON DUPLICATE KEY UPDATE](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/insert-on-duplicate.html) might help you, but again, I'm pretty unsure. Sorry. How do you determine a conflict? Can a conflict be expressed in terms of SQL, i.e. some WHERE condition?

Comment: There's only one column in each row that was updated, we'll call it `other_id`. In conjunction, I also have a `SerialNumber` column. The `other_id` is the only one that changed, so we could possibly restore the backup to a different db name, then do a cross db `UPDATE`/`WHERE` query where the serial numbers match.